# why "undefined" show in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am getting undefined in console .log.I am trying to get get data from my view .could you please tell me why it is not showing the model data .I will explain thing in other words

I have this in my **login.html** file

```
 <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="username">
            </label>
```

I want to access **username** in my controller .controller name is **authenticationCntrl**

```
 function authenticationCntrl($scope,$state) {
        console.log('=====authenticationCntrl controller call')
         console.log($scope.username)
        console.log($scope.password)
         $scope.forgetPassword=function(){
            console.log($scope.username)
            console.log("dddd")
            console.log($scope.password)

        }
```

I filled my username and password when I click "forget password" I get undefined value why ?

here is my code
http://goo.gl/Nte89L

click **preview** to check output

Comment: Maybe it's just Monday morning but I can't see where you define $scope.username or $scope.password.

Comment: @LeeWillis it is on controller .. authenticationCntrl.js file. in this director js-->auth-->controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered the `.` problem. From this article [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use
>
> input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1" rather than
>
> input type="text" ng-model="prop1".

In your controller define a container object:

```
$scope.obj = {};
```

And in your HTML:

```
ng-model="obj.username"
ng-model="obj.password"
```

Comment: correct..it is working ..but why simple username and pasword not work ?